# What do I need to change in NGINX official Docker's image to have the set-misc-nginx module?

Tags: docker, nginx

I need to use the random number generator from [this library](https://github.com/openresty/set-misc-nginx-module#installation), but I wanted to use the [official nginx image](https://github.com/nginxinc/docker-nginx/blob/e3bbc1131a683dabf868268e62b9d3fbd250191b/mainline/buster/Dockerfile), so I was trying to see its source code and perform the changes required to have this library installed.

But I am at loss, as the instructions don't seem to fit with the way NGINX is being installed in that Dockerfile.

How can I install set-misc-nginx within the official NGINX Dockerfile?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You can extend the [official ngnix](https://hub.docker.com/_/nginx) to build the dynamic modules then load them in `nginx`:

```
# syntax=docker/dockerfile:experimental
ARG NGINX_VERSION
FROM nginx:${NGINX_VERSION} as build

RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y \
        openssh-client \
        git \
        wget \
        libxml2 \
        libxslt1-dev \
        libpcre3 \
        libpcre3-dev \
        zlib1g \
        zlib1g-dev \
        openssl \
        libssl-dev \
        libtool \
        automake \
        gcc \
        g++ \
        make && \
    rm -rf /var/cache/apt

RUN wget "http://nginx.org/download/nginx-${NGINX_VERSION}.tar.gz" && \
    tar -C /usr/src -xzvf nginx-${NGINX_VERSION}.tar.gz

RUN mkdir -p -m 0600 ~/.ssh && \
    ssh-keyscan github.com >> ~/.ssh/known_hosts

WORKDIR /src/ngx_devel_kit
RUN --mount=type=ssh git clone git@github.com:simpl/ngx_devel_kit .

WORKDIR /src/set-misc-nginx-module
RUN --mount=type=ssh git clone git@github.com:openresty/set-misc-nginx-module.git .

WORKDIR /usr/src/nginx-${NGINX_VERSION}
RUN NGINX_ARGS=$(nginx -V 2>&1 | sed -n -e 's/^.*arguments: //p') \
    ./configure --with-compat --with-http_ssl_module --add-dynamic-module=/src/ngx_devel_kit --add-dynamic-module=/src/set-misc-nginx-module ${NGINX_ARGS} && \
    make modules

FROM nginx:${NGINX_VERSION}

COPY nginx.conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
COPY --from=build /usr/src/nginx-${NGINX_VERSION}/objs/ngx_http_set_misc_module.so /usr/src/nginx-${NGINX_VERSION}/objs/ndk_http_module.so /usr/lib/nginx/modules/
```

**Note**: this example is a [multi-staged build](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/multistage-build/) that uses the `docker` [build enhancements](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/build_enhancements/) to clone the repositories (depending on your version of `docker` you may have to [enable experimental features](https://github.com/docker/docker-ce/blob/master/components/cli/experimental/README.md)).

You can load the modules in the `nginx.conf` that's copied in the final image:

```
user  nginx;
worker_processes  1;

error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log warn;
pid        /var/run/nginx.pid;

load_module /usr/lib/nginx/modules/ndk_http_module.so;
load_module /usr/lib/nginx/modules/ngx_http_set_misc_module.so;

events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}

http {
    ...
}
```

Build the image: `DOCKER_BUILDKIT=1 docker build --rm --ssh=default --build-arg NGINX_VERSION=1.17.3 --network host -t so:57739560 .`

Run the container: `docker run --rm -it -p 80:80 so:57739560`

For another example of building dynamic modules using the official `nginx` image you can check out my [nginx-modsecurity](https://github.com/masseybradley/nginx-modsecurity) repo (`nginx` image extended with [Modsecurity](https://github.com/SpiderLabs/ModSecurity) and [Modsecurity-nginx](https://github.com/SpiderLabs/ModSecurity-nginx)).

Comment: wow , thanks for the answer, so much new stuff to learn! I have one question: If you are coming `FROM nginx:${NGINX_VERSION}`, why are you downloading nginx again in this command `RUN wget "http://nginx.org/download/nginx-${NGINX_VERSION}.tar.gz" && ...`?

Comment: @PedroD I’m downloading the sources of the same version as the image for the build stage to `make` the modules.

Comment: @Christoph Kluge thanks for the edit, noticed that as well but never got around to updating it.

Comment: Are we really extending the official image ? We are just building again a new nginx in it, no ?

Comment: The modules are built in the first stage and extend the [official nginx image](https://hub.docker.com/_/nginx) in the second stage in docker speaking, note the second `FROM nginx:${NGINX_VERSION}` in the `Dockerfile`. In a multi-staged build this is basically "starting from a new copy of the official nginx image and add the modules that we just built in it", we don't rebuild nginx in the final stage.

Comment: hum, cool, I have got the hint. I will try to follow the same logic. I need to build nginx with modsecurity and lua, based on alpine, with crontab and certbot of Let'sEncrypt :-)

Comment: You can clone my [`nginx-modsecurity`](https://github.com/masseybradley/nginx-modsecurity) as a starting point, just pass the `NGINX_VERSION` `--build-arg` as a i.e. `<version>-alpine` tag and change the `apt-get install`'s with `apk` install's. Shouldn't be too hard to adapt.

Comment: Yes, thanks. I started from your Dockerfile, and I am adapting it, because https://github.com/SpiderLabs/owasp-modsecurity-crs migrated to https://github.com/coreruleset/coreruleset
I will publish mine when I finish

Answer (score 3):

There is a way to add 3rd party modules as shared in the link https://github.com/nginxinc/docker-nginx/tree/master/modules

1. Checkout the docker-nginx code
2. Switch to the modules directory
3. Docker build by specifying set-misc module

```
docker build --build-arg ENABLED_MODULES="ndk set-misc" -t my-nginx-with-set-misc.
```