# How can I use environment variables with lua in nginx container

Tags: docker, nginx, lua

I want to use nginx on a container and that the nginx will read the environment variables of the container. I've searched and found that using lua modules makes it possible but for some reason I can't load the lua modules on the nginx itself. Please help, adding Dockerfile and nginx.conf 
**Dockerfile**

```
FROM nginx:1.15-alpine

RUN  mkdir -p /run/nginx && \
     apk add nginx-mod-http-lua

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY build /usr/src/app/build
COPY mime.types /usr/src/app

COPY nginx.conf /usr/src/app

EXPOSE 8080

CMD [ "nginx", "-c", "/usr/src/app/nginx.conf", "-g", "daemon off;" ]
```

**nginx.conf**

```
load_module /usr/lib/nginx/modules/ndk_http_module.so;
load_module /usr/lib/nginx/modules/ngx_http_lua_module.so;

pcre_jit on;

events {

}

http {
    server {
        listen 8080;
        set_by_lua $db_api 'return os.getenv("DB_API")';
        location /db/ {
            proxy_pass $db_api;
        }

        location / {
            root /usr/src/app/build;
            index index.html;
        }
    }
}
```

and these are the errors I get:

```
2020/09/24 17:06:49 [alert] 1#1: detected a LuaJIT version which is not OpenResty's; many optimizations will be disabled and performance will be compromised (see https://github.com/openresty/luajit2 for OpenResty's LuaJIT or, even better, consider using the OpenResty releases from https://openresty.org/en/download.html)
nginx: [alert] detected a LuaJIT version which is not OpenResty's; many optimizations will be disabled and performance will be compromised (see https://github.com/openresty/luajit2 for OpenResty's LuaJIT or, even better, consider using the OpenResty releases from https://openresty.org/en/download.html)
2020/09/24 17:06:49 [error] 1#1: lua_load_resty_core failed to load the resty.core module from https://github.com/openresty/lua-resty-core; ensure you are using an OpenResty release from https://openresty.org/en/download.html (rc: 2, reason: module 'resty.core' not found:
        no field package.preload['resty.core']
        no file './resty/core.lua'
        no file '/usr/share/luajit-2.1.0-beta3/resty/core.lua'
        no file '/usr/local/share/lua/5.1/resty/core.lua'
        no file '/usr/local/share/lua/5.1/resty/core/init.lua'
        no file '/usr/share/lua/5.1/resty/core.lua'
        no file '/usr/share/lua/5.1/resty/core/init.lua'
        no file '/usr/share/lua/common/resty/core.lua'
        no file '/usr/share/lua/common/resty/core/init.lua'
        no file './resty/core.so'
        no file '/usr/local/lib/lua/5.1/resty/core.so'
        no file '/usr/lib/lua/5.1/resty/core.so'
        no file '/usr/local/lib/lua/5.1/loadall.so'
        no file './resty.so'
        no file '/usr/local/lib/lua/5.1/resty.so'
        no file '/usr/lib/lua/5.1/resty.so'
        no file '/usr/local/lib/lua/5.1/loadall.so')
nginx: [error] lua_load_resty_core failed to load the resty.core module from https://github.com/openresty/lua-resty-core; ensure you are using an OpenResty release from https://openresty.org/en/download.html (rc: 2, reason: module 'resty.core' not found:
        no field package.preload['resty.core']
        no file './resty/core.lua'
        no file '/usr/share/luajit-2.1.0-beta3/resty/core.lua'
        no file '/usr/local/share/lua/5.1/resty/core.lua'
        no file '/usr/local/share/lua/5.1/resty/core/init.lua'
        no file '/usr/share/lua/5.1/resty/core.lua'
        no file '/usr/share/lua/5.1/resty/core/init.lua'
        no file '/usr/share/lua/common/resty/core.lua'
        no file '/usr/share/lua/common/resty/core/init.lua'
        no file './resty/core.so'
        no file '/usr/local/lib/lua/5.1/resty/core.so'
        no file '/usr/lib/lua/5.1/resty/core.so'
        no file '/usr/local/lib/lua/5.1/loadall.so'
        no file './resty.so'
        no file '/usr/local/lib/lua/5.1/resty.so'
        no file '/usr/lib/lua/5.1/resty.so'
        no file '/usr/local/lib/lua/5.1/loadall.so')
```

and this is the docker build and run commands:

```
docker build -t client:1.0.0 --no-cache .

docker run -p 80:8080 -it -e DB_API=DB_API_URL client:1.0.0
```

Comment: You could [disable the loading of resty core](https://github.com/openresty/lua-nginx-module/issues/1509#issuecomment-486122328). Can always [make the modules you need](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57741684/1423507) from scratch which might help as well.

Comment: worked for that lua_resty_load error but now I get this error when I try to proxy the request with the env variable ```[error] 6#6: *2 invalid URL prefix in ""```

Comment: proxy_pass awaits url like `http://localhost:8080` but you passing string `DB_API_URL` as `$db_api`

Comment: This is the docker run command that I use
```docker run -p 80:8080 -it -e DB_API='http://52.138.174.189:8080/clientToDBApi'  client:1.0.0```

Comment: Or even that command ```docker run -p 80:8080 -it -e DB_API=http://52.138.174.189:8080/clientToDBApi client:1.0.0```

Comment: I needed to add the env directive, however now I'm getting 404 but if I write the URL hardcoded I dont get it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `env` directive in the top and it works with the comments of the question it works