# How do we install dynamic modules (non support officially) on Nginx Ingress Controller? (terraform, helm chart)

Tags: docker, nginx, kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, nginx-ingress

I'm managing Kubernetes + nginx.

I'd like to install dynamic modules on nginx that are provided by Nginx Ingress Controller.
Those dynamic modules are not offered by Nginx Ingress Controller official configmap (https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/user-guide/nginx-configuration/configmap/)

So I believe, I need to build my own Docker container of Nginx Ingress Controller.
(Could be added at this? https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/blob/8951b7e22ad3952c549150f61d7346f272c563e1/images/nginx/rootfs/build.sh#L618-L632 )

Do you know how we can customize the controller and manage it by helm chart? I'm thinking about making a Fork branch from the controller master repo on Github.
But I don't have any idea on how we install a customized version of the controller on terraform + helm chart.

However, I would prefer to use a non-customizable solution (because of some annotation settings)

Environment:
Kubernetes
Nginx Ingress Controller is installed by helm chart + terraform
Nginx Ingress Controller -> https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/tree/main/charts/ingress-nginx

Terraform:

```
resource "helm_release" "nginx-ingress-controller" {
  name      = "nginx-ingress-controller"
  chart     = "ingress-nginx/ingress-nginx"
  namespace = "kube-system"
  version   = "3.34.0"
}
```

dynamic modules
https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/dynamic-modules/dynamic-modules/
(install process might be using `--add-dynamic-module` option, and set `load_module modules/something.so` on `nginx.conf` via `ingress.yaml`)

Thank you.

Comment: Instead of modifying (and maintain a modified fork) you might consider to create an own docler image with the nginx image as "BASE".

Comment: You could also mount a volume with the plugin and then load the plugin from the configmap.

Answer (score 1):

## TL;DR

Extend the official image with the dynamic modules, and update the `helm_release` `terraform` resource to `set` the `controller.image.registry`, `controller.image.image`, `controller.image.tag`, `controller.image.digest`, and `controller.image.digestChroot` for your custom image along with a `controller.config.main-snippet` to load the dynamic module(s) in the main context.

---

This is similar to my previous [answer for building modules using the official nginx image](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57741684/1423507). You can extend the `ingress-nginx/controller` image, build the modules in one stage, extend the official image with the dynamic modules in another stage, and use the image in your `helm_release`. An example for extending the `ingress-nginx/controller` with the [`echo-nginx-module`](https://github.com/openresty/echo-nginx-module) e.g.:

### Docker

```
ARG INGRESS_NGINX_CONTROLLER_VERSION
FROM registry.k8s.io/ingress-nginx/controller:${INGRESS_NGINX_CONTROLLER_VERSION} as build

ARG INGRESS_NGINX_CONTROLLER_VERSION
ENV INGRESS_NGINX_CONTROLLER_VERSION=${INGRESS_NGINX_CONTROLLER_VERSION}

USER root
RUN apk add \
        automake \
        ca-certificates \
        curl \
        gcc \
        g++ \
        make \
        pcre-dev \
        zlib-dev

RUN NGINX_VERSION=$(nginx -V 2>&1 |sed -n -e 's/nginx version: //p' |cut -d'/' -f2); \
    curl -L "http://nginx.org/download/nginx-${NGINX_VERSION}.tar.gz" | tar -C /tmp/nginx --strip-components=1 -xz

WORKDIR /src/echo-nginx-module
RUN curl -L https://github.com/openresty/echo-nginx-module/archive/refs/tags/v0.63.tar.gz | tar --strip-components=1 -xz

WORKDIR /tmp/nginx
RUN ./configure --with-compat --add-dynamic-module=/src/echo-nginx-module && \
    make modules

FROM registry.k8s.io/ingress-nginx/controller:${INGRESS_NGINX_CONTROLLER_VERSION}

COPY --from=build /tmp/nginx/objs/ngx_http_echo_module.so /etc/nginx/modules/
```

... build and push the image e.g.: `docker build --rm -t myrepo/ingress-nginx/controller:v1.5.1-echo --build-arg INGRESS_NGINX_CONTROLLER_VERSION=v1.5.1 . && docker push myrepo/ingress-nginx/controller:v1.5.1-echo`

### Terraform

Update the `terraform` `helm_release` resource to install the charts using the custom image and adding a [`main-snippet`](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/user-guide/nginx-configuration/configmap/#main-snippet) to set the [`load_module`](https://nginx.org/en/docs/ngx_core_module.html#load_module) directive in the `main` context:

```hcl
resource "helm_release" "ingress-nginx" {
  name       = "ingress-nginx"
  namespace  = "kube-system"
  repository = "https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx"
  chart      = "ingress-nginx"
  version    = "3.34.0"
  set {
    name = "controller.image.registry"
    value = "myrepo"
  }
  set {
    name = "controller.image.image"
    value = "ingress-nginx/controller"
  }
  set {
    name = "controller.image.tag"
    value = "v1.5.1-echo"
  }
  set {
    name = "controller.image.digest"
    value = "sha256:1b32b3e8c983ef4a32d87dead51fbbf2a2c085f1deff6aa27a212ca6beefcb72"
  }
  set {
    name = "controller.image.digestChroot"
    value = "sha256:f2e1146adeadac8eebb251284f45f8569beef9c6ec834ae1335d26617da6af2d"
  }
  set {
    name = "controller.config.main-snippet"
    value = <<EOF
load_module /etc/nginx/modules/ngx_http_echo_module.so;
EOF
  }
}
```

The `controller.image.digest` is the image `RepoDigest`: `docker inspect myrepo/ingress-nginx/controller:v1.5.1-echo --format '{{range .RepoDigests}}{{println .}}{{end}}' |cut -d'@' -f2`

The `controller.image.digestChroot` is the `Parent` sha: `docker inspect myrepo/ingress-nginx/controller:v1.5.1-echo --format {{.Parent}}`

### Test

1. Create a `nginx` pod: `kubectl run nginx --image=nginx`
2. Expose the pod: `kubectl expose pod nginx --port 80 --target-port 80`
3. Create an ingress with a `server-snippet`:

```
cat <<EOF | kubectl apply -f -
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: nginx
  annotations:
    cert-manager.io/cluster-issuer: letsencrypt-prod
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/server-snippet: |
      location /hello {
        echo "hello, world!";
      }
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
spec:
  rules:
  - host: echo.example.com
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /
        pathType: ImplementationSpecific
        backend:
          service:
            name: nginx
            port:
              number: 80
  tls:
  - hosts:
    - echo.example.com
    secretName: tls-echo
EOF
```

> Using [`cert-manager`](https://cert-manager.io/docs/) for TLS certificates issuance and [`external-dns`](https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/external-dns) for DNS management.

4. Test using `curl`:

[image: curl echo module test on publicly exposed app]

Answer (score 0):

Please take a look at [Cloud Native Buildpacks](https://buildpacks.io/).
Images can be built directly from application source without additional instructions.

Maybe this [nginx-buildpack](https://github.com/paketo-buildpacks/nginx) solves your problem:

> Loading dynamic modules
> You can use templates to set the path to a dynamic module using the load_module directive.

PS. https://12factor.net/build-release-run

> The twelve-factor app uses strict separation between the build, release, and run stages. For example, it is impossible to make changes to the code at runtime, since there is no way to propagate those changes back to the build stage.